# How to change Firefox interface language

Tags: windows-10, firefox, language, localization

I have no idea who thought it's smart to make this change difficult. My OS is English, yet when I installed Firefox, it decided to run in Czech. That makes it difficult to share error messages and other developper-related things with other people who do not speak Czech, or googling those messages.

I went to settings, where I searched "Jazyk", which means "Language":

[image]

The description says "Select languages used for displaying pages." I hope me having to translate stuff on the screenshots is sufficient to illustrate why I am angry that language change is not possible.

[On Mozzila help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-another-language#w_switch-firefox-to-another-language), it says this:

> ### Switch Firefox to another language
>
> You can switch languages at any time to display Firefox menus,
> notifications and messages in a different language.
>
> 1. Click the menu button <kbd>☰</kbd> Menu and select <kbd>Options</kbd>.
> 2. In the Language section of the General panel, choose a language in the drop-down menu.
> 3. Restart Firefox.
>
> To add languages, see the next section.

There is no dropdown menu. I did try to move "English" to the top in the menu that is there and restart.

[image]

No effect, UI is still Czech.

So is it possible to change UI language?

Comment: Have you tried to download an English version of Firefox specifically?

Comment: I was downloading from the official page, it does not ask what language you want.

Comment: You will have to manually go to the release archive to find the English executable yourself.  You can also use a proxy/vpn to trick Mozilla's Geo location script.

Comment: I already found a solution that doesn't require re-install, but it's almost as ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Firefox devs decided that changing a language is super advanced feature, and thus you need to do it through the internal settings:

1. Go to `about:config`.
2. Confirm that you accept the risk of doing super advanced things such as changing UI language
3. Search for `intl.locale.requested`. In my case it did not exist, if it does not then create it as a string value
4. Enter the locale code (ie. `en-us`). You can also leave the setting empty, and the language of your OS will be used.